# Timestamp format from HH:MM:SS to HH:MM:SS.SSSSSS in BQ

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, datetime-format

I need to display a datetime value from YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSSSSS in Google Big Query. For example, the source data is : 2023-06-23 00:00:00 and I want my results like in below format:
2023-06-23 00:00:00.000000.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a specific format when there is no *MICROSECOND* (microsecond = 0) :

```
WITH Input AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP("2008-12-25 05:30:00") AS timestamp_value
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TIMESTAMP("2008-12-25 05:30:00.123456")
)
SELECT
  CASE WHEN ( EXTRACT(MICROSECOND FROM timestamp_value) > 0 )
       THEN FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F %H:%M:%E*S", timestamp_value)
       ELSE FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F %H:%M:%E*S.000000", timestamp_value)
  END AS converted
FROM Input
```

Result :

| timestamp_value | converted |
| --- | --- |
| 2008-12-25 05:30:00 UTC 2008-12-25 | 05:30:00.000000 |
| 2008-12-25 05:30:00.123456 UTC | 2008-12-25 05:30:00.123456 |

[EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#extract) to Returns a value that corresponds to the specified part from a supplied datetime_expression ( `EXTRACT(part FROM datetime_expression)` ).

[FORMAT_TIMESTAMP](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#format_timestamp) to formats a timestamp according to the specified format_string.